# How to keep a counter incremented after :hover detection?

Tags: html, css, counter, z-index

Here is my HTML page. They are 2 grids as the yellow one superimposed, using absolute position and z-index. I'm trying to display, changing the z-index, one grid or the other.
The control panel below uses `:hover` to detect and increment (+), decrement (-) or reset (0) the counters.

[image: render]

The question is : how to keep counters' value after not being on `:hover` e.g. having a counter initialized at 0, how to get the value 2 after `:hover`ing on and away twice ?

Then, how to link these values to the `z-index` of the `#wrapper1` and `#wrapper2` ?

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  counter-reset: zindex1;
  counter-reset: zindex2;
}

[id^="wrapper"] {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(4, 50px) / repeat(4, 50px);
}

[id^="wrapper"] > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#wrapper1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

#wrapper2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
}

#wrapper1 > div {
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

#wrapper2 > div {
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
}

#px250 {
  height: 250px;
}

#control {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 50px) / repeat(4, 50px);
}

[id^="nmbr"],
[id^="less"],
[id^="plus"],
[id^="rsst"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: lightgray;
}

[id^="nmbr"] {
  background-color: grey;
}

[id^="less"]:hover {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

[id^="plus"]:hover {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

[id^="rsst"]:hover {
  background-color: azure;
}

#less1:hover {
  counter-increment: zinde12 -1;
}

#less2:hover {
  counter-increment: zindex2 -1;
}

#plus1:hover {
  counter-increment: zindex1 1;
}

#plus2:hover {
  counter-increment: zindex2 1;
}

#rsst1:hover {
  counter-reset: zindex1;
}

#rsst2:hover {
  counter-reset: zindex2;
}

#nmbr1 p::after {
  content: " " counter(zindex1);
}

#nmbr2 p::after {
  content: " " counter(zindex2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PURE CSS</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link src="./src/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wrapper1">
      <div>01</div>
      <div>02</div>
      <div>03</div>
      <div>04</div>
      <div>05</div>
      <div>06</div>
      <div>07</div>
      <div>08</div>
      <div>09</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>11</div>
      <div>12</div>
      <div>13</div>
      <div>14</div>
      <div>15</div>
      <div>16</div>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper2">
      <div>01</div>
      <div>02</div>
      <div>03</div>
      <div>04</div>
      <div>05</div>
      <div>06</div>
      <div>07</div>
      <div>08</div>
      <div>09</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>11</div>
      <div>12</div>
      <div>13</div>
      <div>14</div>
      <div>15</div>
      <div>16</div>
    </div>

    <div id="px250"></div>

    <div id="control">
      <div id="nmbr1"><p>1 :</p></div>
      <div id="less1"><p>-</p></div>
      <div id="plus1"><p>+</p></div>
      <div id="rsst1"><p>0</p></div>
      <div id="nmbr2"><p>2 :</p></div>
      <div id="less2"><p>-</p></div>
      <div id="plus2"><p>+</p></div>
      <div id="rsst2"><p>0</p></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: you cannot with pure CSS. CSS is stateless and in your case you need to keep track of your actions to change the value so you need a way to store the value

Comment: @TemaniAfif can't I create checkbox input that I turn on checked after :hover a first over, a second one after another :hover and count them ?

Comment: you cannot turn something checked with hover, you will need a click

Answer (score 1):

You need to do all that in JavaScript because CSS is stateless.